# Создать два шаблонных класса, которые могут конструироваться друг из друга

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Файл A.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "B.h"

template<class T>
struct A {
    A(B<T>& p);
};

template<class T>
A<T>::A(B<T>& p) {

}
```

Файл B.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h"

template<class T>
struct B {
    B(A<T>& p);
};

template<class T>
B<T>::B(A<T>& p) {

}
```

Файл main.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тикие проблемы решаются предекларацией, но я точно не уверен можно ли предекларировать шаблонные классы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

a.h:

```
#pragma once

template<class T>
struct B;

template<class T>
struct A {
    A(B<T>& p);
};

template<class T>
A<T>::A(B<T>& p) {

}
```

b.h:

```
#pragma once


template<class T>
struct A;


template<class T>
struct B {
    B(A<T>& p);
};

template<class T>
B<T>::B(A<T>& p) {

}
```